# Simple Svelte code works in REPL but not in VSCode

Tags: javascript, svelte

I'm learning Svelte and the code is as simple as the following, it works on Svelte REPL but in VSCode (localhost server) the h2 tag doesn't get updated as the input value changes.

```
<script>
    let val = '';
</script>

<svelte:head>
    <title>About page</title>
</svelte:head>

<div>
    <h1>About</h1>
    <input type="text" bind:value={val} />
    <h2>value is: {val}</h2>
</div>
```

[image: in VSCode the code doesn't work]

[image: Svelte REPL works]

I'm confused, what would be the problem? should I change a settings in Svelte config files?

Answer (score 0):

That could happen if [hydration](https://kit.svelte.dev/docs#ssr-and-javascript-hydrate) is turned off:

Look for:
`export const hydrate = false;` in the routes/*.svelte file or check if hydrate is turned off in the `svelte.config.js`

Another option could be that an exception in another file caused the svelte scheduler to hang, check your console for errors.

Comment: Thanks @bob-fanger for your great help. as I'm a newbie in Svelte I accidentally removed the `div` with the id of `#svelte` and in the `svelte.config.js` file it says `hydrate the <div id="svelte"> element in src/app.html`. So adding that div back to the `app.html` did the trick and all is working fine now.